# Array and pointers in c

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, integer, memory-address

```
int x[7] = { 100,200,300,400,500,600,700};
int *y = (int *)(&x + 1);
printf(“%d”,*(y-1));
```

**How does value of y is pointing to the last of the array after line 2?**

Answer (score 2):

`&x` has type of `int (*)[7]` which means pointer to array of 7 integers.

If you add `1` to this pointer you "move" to the next array of 7 integers, which is past the original array.

[image]

Strictly it is undefined behaviour as you access the element outside the referenced object.

Comment: LOlz. that's the most in-your-face, yet outstandingly accurate graphic I've seen in a long time. Nice.